# Fail to use function template with array as parameter inside a class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I created a function template.
It works fine if I use it in functions.
Now, I'd like to use it inside a class but can't make the code compile:

```
#include <QList>

// Function template
template <typename T>
void Array2QList(QList<T> &outList, const T in[], int &insize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < insize; ++i)
        outList.append(in[i]);
}

// Class using the template    
class Parser
{
public:
    Parser(const unsigned char buffer[], const int numBytes){
        Array2QList<>(frame, buffer, numBytes); // This one fails
    }
    ~Parser(){}
    QList<unsigned char> frame;
};

// Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size = 50;
    unsigned char buffer[size];

    QList<unsigned char> frame;

    Array2QList<unsigned char>(frame, buffer, size); // This one works

    Parser parser = Parser(buffer, size);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

> ..\SandBox\main.cpp: In constructor 'Parser::Parser(const unsigned
> char*, int)':
>
> ..\SandBox\main.cpp:20: error: no matching function for
> call to 'Array2QList(QList&, const unsigned char*&, const int&)'

*Note: I must arrays since it is an interface for a USB driver.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array2QList<>(frame, buffer, numBytes);
```

Here, `numBytes` is a `const int`, but `Array2QList` takes an `int&`. You can't bind a non-`const` reference to something that's `const`. It's unclear why you are taking that parameter by reference, so if you just pass by value instead, it'll work.

```
template <typename T>
void Array2QList(QList<T> &outList, const T in[], int insize){
//                                     get rid of &  ^
```

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed the const. I got confused since I have 2 functions with the same name but not the same parameters. The other one uses a reference to the size because the array is allocated inside the function. In the case I don't need the reference... But I wrongly kept it.